# Generating functions: conceptual flaw in my understanding?

Tags: probability, expectation

$$G_X(t)=e^{(t+2)(t-1)}$$

Is it true that $X$ follows $Po(t+2)$ then? Because the generating function can be rewritten as

$$G_X(t)=\sum_{x=0}^∞ t^x\frac{e^{-t-2}(t+2)^x}{x!}$$

and then there would be an inconsistency with $$E(X)=G_X'(1)=3≠t+2$$

There would also be an inconsistency with

$$Var(X)=G_X''(1)+G_X'(1)-[G_X'(1)]^2=5≠t+2$$

and

$$P(X=1)=G_X'(0)=e^{-2}≠e^{-t-2}(t+2)$$

Someone help me with my misconception?

Comment: The probability generating function of a (positive, discrete) random variable $X$ is defined as $G_X(s) = E[s^X]$. Here $s$ is the argument of the function, a dummy variable which is functionally independent of the parameters of $X$ (if any). The pgf of $\text{Poisson}(\lambda)$ is $G_X(s) = e^{\lambda(s - 1)}$, and obviously you cannot put $\lambda = s + 2$ and expect the resulting expression having the same behavior.

Comment: @bgm well explained, thanks.